# Saxon-HE on Android

Tags: android, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm trying to perform XLST 2.0 transforms on android using Saxon-He 9.5.1-5. The problem is that the following code:

```
    final Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(context.getAssets().open(styleSheet));

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    factory.setURIResolver(new URIResolver() {
        @Override
        public Source resolve(final String href, final String base) throws TransformerException {
            Source source = null;

            try {
                source = new StreamSource(context.getAssets().open(href));
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.i("ERROR", Log.getStackTraceString(t));
            }

            return source;
        }
    });
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
```

results in transformer being null. The xsltSource variable is an XSLT file in my assets directory. In logcat I'm seeing the following error

```
W/System.err﹕ SystemId Unknown; Line #12; Column #8; Could not find function: tokenize
```

I found that prefixing the method tokenize() with "fn:" solved this problem, but recompiling resulted in similar errors for all the other functions declared in my XSLT file. Prefixing all those functions with "fn:" lead me to an error with "instance of". This seems like a rabbit hole and was wondering if anyone has had experience with this? I can't post the XSLT files as they're confidential to my customer, however I know that they are all valid as they run just fine server-side using the same Saxon-HE lib. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it is Saxon 9 that you use on Android? The error messages sound more as if you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor. Try instantiating `TransformerFactory factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();` directly.

Comment: I agree that this sounds like 1.0 processing, however I've tried explicitly calling

    TransformerFactory factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();

Comment: I have never used Saxon on Android. Do you get any stylesheet compiled and executed at all, for instance http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/processorTest2.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that I've gotten XQuery with Saxon working on Android with the following workarounds:

1. Remove the javax.* packages from the Saxon jar file
2. Don't use the DOMWrapper or DOMSource - the harmony DOM implementation is incomplete and breaks Saxon. Use Configuration.buildDocument with a SAXSource.

Here's some example code:

```
 import net.sf.saxon.Configuration;
 import net.sf.saxon.DynamicQueryContext;
 import net.sf.saxon.XQueryExpression;
 import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
 import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
 import org.w3c.dom.Node;
 import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
 ...
 Configuration config = Configuration.newConfiguration();
 InputSource src = ...;
 SAXParser saxParser =...;
 SAXSource ss = new SAXSource(saxParser.getXMLReader(), src);
 dqc.setContextItem(config.buildDocument(ss));

 DynamicQueryContext dqc = 
     new DynamicQueryContext(config);
 dqc.setContextItem(config.buildDocument(new DOMSource(contextNode)));
 XQueryExpression query = ...;
 Object result = query.evaluateSingle(dqc);
```